# Ping from google cloud vm ubuntu to my local machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timeout, ping, firewall, ubuntu-18.04

When I try to ping from Google cloud's vm instances to my local computer, it times out.

i.e... ping 192.168.43.***
Times out.

But, when I ping google.com from same console,  it works.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 image on vm.
And is hosting my vm on compute engine.

ping google.com
Works

I think,  there is something wrong with firewall. Please help me to write required firewall rule, so my ping incoming traffic is not blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Your issue is not related to Google Cloud VMs.  From your post, you think your local computers IP address is 192.168.x.x ... which it is ... but that is a private IP and is never going to be reachable from anywhere on the Internet.

See Wikipedia - [Private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

If you want to reach your local PC for an incoming connection, you will likely have to setup a router path at your local end.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses in the range of 192.168.x.x are part of the [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) private IP addresses.  Assuming you are not on a VPN with your cloud instance, you won't be able to ping this address in either direction (e.g. you can't ping this address on your cloud instance from your local machine, and if this is the address of your local machine, your cloud instance won't be able to reach it).

In addition to needing the firewall to allow passing of ICMP traffic, you would need to ping an externally visible address (for example, what shows up when you go to http://www.whatismyip.com, though this is unlikely to be your actual machine, it is more likely to be whatever device is providing NAT for you).

On the other hand, if you want to set up a VPN, you can [look at the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview).